# Speed up COUNT(*) when using an index

Tags: mysql, index, performance, mysql-5.5, count, query-performance

I have a table similar to this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY (category)
);
```

This table has over `10,000,000 rows`, at around `12 categories`. So each category has an average of `833,333 books`.

When querying for count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books WHERE category=1;
```

Even though it's using an index when querying, this takes quite a long time to complete (several seconds.) How would you optimize this?

Previously, I had increased a number every time I inserted to books (into a table that relates category -> book count.) But our code is complicated, and many places insert or delete books. I know it's possible to solve this with `EVENTS`, but I'm asking maybe there's a MySQL feature I missed.

Comment: can you add the output of an explain of your query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query will be slow because cardinality of `category` index is low. There are 12 categories, so in average the query will read 1/12 part of the index. You can't improve this query.

Your original approach can improve overall performance. Just instead of manually updating `book_count` create a trigger on INSERT and DELETE event.

**UPDATE:** To prove the query will partially read index `category`

```
mysql> select count(*) from books;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select category, count(*) from books group by 1;
+----------+----------+
| category | count(*) |
+----------+----------+
|        0 |       50 |
|        1 |       77 |
|        2 |       88 |
|        3 |       84 |
|        4 |      102 |
|        5 |       79 |
|        6 |       79 |
|        7 |       73 |
|        8 |       84 |
|        9 |       76 |
|       10 |       87 |
|       11 |       83 |
|       12 |       38 |
+----------+----------+
13 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> flush status;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from books where category = 6;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       79 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show status like 'Hand%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 2     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 0     |
| Handler_read_key           | 1     |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 79    |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 0     |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 0     |
+----------------------------+-------+
18 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: The query only reads 1/12th of the index to count all books of category 1? How should that work? When does it stop to read the index?

Comment: To count records in the index you need to read them, don't you?

Comment: For better understanding how indexes work http://www.slideshare.net/akuzminsky/indexes-in-my-sql-aleksandr-kuzminsky-https-twindbcom

Comment: What is the result of your query? Does category 1 has around the average? Or it is way bigger?

Comment: That particular `SELECT` will reach into `INDEX(category)`, which is stored as a [BTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), and scan however many index records are there are rows with the given `category`.  Then it is finished.  The more records, the longer it will take; there is no avoiding it (for that `SELECT`).

Comment: Fwiw, InnoDB indexes are B+tree

Answer (score -3):

my trick is, make temporary table with field category and units then u make schedule at night to counting it n save to your temporary table, then ur just read that table with just 12 row in it, very faster, but ur count H-1, u need liitle trick againt to add current day ...

Comment: Welcome to the site! While pre-computing the information is a sound strategy, it may not be possible in all scenarios. Could you expand on your answer to provide a solution to speeding up the query without pre-computing the results?